# Any guidance for new beginners interested in data science

Tags: learning

I am a student with a master degree in biostatistics. I am interested in data science. I know SAS and R. No experience with python. May I ask for your experts' advice on how to teach myself data science from zero, please?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: This topic is a bit too broad, and has been touched upon in many other posts, particularly: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/how-to-self-learn-data-science

which was also closed for being too broad.

Comment: Just start with an intro course - there are lots of free MOOCs offering data science classes. Then you will have more specific questions which might be answerable, and you will know enough terminology to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to learn data science you should know about main tools and ideas in the data scientist's toolbox. 
Two steps which most newbee's follow are:

1. The first is a conceptual introduction to the ideas behind turning data into actionable knowledge which involves following steps:

> > Getting and Cleaning Data,Data Analysis,Reproducible Research

---

> > Statistical Inference, using Regression Models and Machine Learning

2. The second is a practical introduction to the tools that will be used in the program like version control, markdown, git, GitHub, R, and RStudio.

I would advice you to complete a general course on data science from any website or tutorial you find easy for example I personally like this course: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhu-data-science

And then start building some projects of your own for example in my free time I build a lot of small data science projects playing with any available data like US census, petroleum data etc. For example see following link for one of my many data science projects: 
https://arjun-chaudhary.shinyapps.io/Data_Analytics/

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, Arjun! I will take a deep look at the course and your project. They looked very interesting.

Comment: No worries mate have a blast.. and just to let you know this market is going crazy and producing highly paid jobs.